# Check if time is between a specific range

Tags: matlab

I have a variable we can call timeCheck, then I use `switch`:

```
switch(datestr(timeCheck, 'HH:MM'))
case'here i want to see if the time is between 09:00 to 11:59'
     do stuff
end
```

Would need some help about how the `case` could be specified.

Comment: `if time >= 09.00 && <=11.59` ? do you need something like that ?

Comment: Yes! But the time is presented as HH:MM

Comment: http://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/datenum.html you can try changing it to a serial number then set the if clause and then change it back to time format ... its a work aruond but it might work

Answer (score 0):

[KiW 's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38118256/check-if-time-is-between-a-specific-range#comment63670218_38118256) would work perfectly.
I add my answer just to set point for you about your `switch` - there is no sense of using it here. You just have to use single `if` statement.

Also you can take a look at useful functions [hour](http://www.mathworks.com/help/finance/hour.html) and [minute](http://www.mathworks.com/help/finance/minute.html)

for example:

```
timeCheck = datestr(now) 
>> timeCheck =
    30-Jun-2016 14:27:41
```

and now:

```
if hour(timeCheck) < 12 && hour(timeCheck)*60 + minute(timeCheck) > 540
% do your staff here
end
```